# Detecting a change in an integer

Tags: java, int, boolean, listener

Is there any way to detect change in an integer?  Such as creating a listener to listen to the integer to detect and change in value it has.  I know this is possible with booleans with a few tricks but I cannot seem to adapt this to an int value.  Does anyone have any idea how this could be done?  I need to know how to do this in the Java language.  Below is code that I found online that allows for a boolean listener.  How can I convert this to an integer listener?

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.EventListener;
import java.util.EventObject;
import java.awt.EventQueue; 

//can u see this austin? can u see this i typed this at 9:33 my time
/**
 * This class uses the EventQueue to process its events, but you should only 
 * really do this if the changes you make have an impact on part of a GUI 
 * eg. adding a button to a JFrame.
 *
 * Otherwise, you should create your own event dispatch thread that can handle
 * change events
 */
public class test1 implements BooleanChangeDispatcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BooleanChangeListener listener = new BooleanChangeListener() { // add this to the class
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(BooleanChangeEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Detected change to: "
                    + event.getDispatcher().getFlag()
                    + " -- event: " + event);
            }
        };

        test1 test = new test1(false);
        test.addBooleanChangeListener(listener);

//        test.setFlag(false); // no change, no event dispatch
//        test.setFlag(true); // changed to true -- event dispatched

    }

    private boolean flag;
    private List<BooleanChangeListener> listeners;

    public test1(boolean initialFlagState) {
        flag = initialFlagState;
        listeners = new ArrayList<BooleanChangeListener>();
    }

    @Override   
    public void addBooleanChangeListener(BooleanChangeListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
        if (this.flag != flag) {
            this.flag = flag;
            dispatchEvent();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    private void dispatchEvent() {
        final BooleanChangeEvent event = new BooleanChangeEvent(this);
        for (BooleanChangeListener l : listeners) {
            dispatchRunnableOnEventQueue(l, event);
        }
    }

    private void dispatchRunnableOnEventQueue(
                final BooleanChangeListener listener, 
                final BooleanChangeEvent event) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                listener.stateChanged(event);
            }
        });
    }

}

interface BooleanChangeDispatcher {

    public void addBooleanChangeListener(BooleanChangeListener listener);
    public boolean getFlag();
    public void setFlag(boolean flag);

}

/**
 * Listener interface for classes interested in knowing about a boolean
 * flag change.
 */
interface BooleanChangeListener extends EventListener {

    public void stateChanged(BooleanChangeEvent event);

}

/** 
 * This class lets the listener know when the change occured and what 
 * object was changed.
 */
class BooleanChangeEvent extends EventObject {

    private final BooleanChangeDispatcher dispatcher;

    public BooleanChangeEvent(BooleanChangeDispatcher dispatcher) {
        super(dispatcher);
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
    }

    // type safe way to get source (as opposed to getSource of EventObject
    public BooleanChangeDispatcher getDispatcher() {
        return dispatcher;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have a preferred language?

Comment: Is this a single integer that is changed from one place? How did you do it with booleans?

Comment: I don't know what "tricks" you are talking about that would work with booleans and not integers.  Show us the code.

Comment: This is a single integer that i need to be able to detect any change to in order to fire an event.  This can be changed from a few different classes.  I do not change it with booleans.  I know how to write a listener to detect a boolean change but i cannot adapt it to an int listener.

Comment: Stephen it is just a word phrase because I did not have any other word for it.  All I need to know is how to listen to any change in value of an integer.

Comment: Can you not share the code for boolean listener?

Comment: @MrDrProfessorTyler - you haven't addressed my comment.  **Why** can't you adapt the code for a boolean listener to a integer listener?  Show us the code.

Comment: Ok code will be posted below.

Comment: @MrDrProfessorTyler Post it in your question. You can edit your own question.

Comment: ok it is in my question now I got this code from someone else so I could figure it out but I can't adapt it no matter how hard I try I am new to making a custom listener so bear with me.

Comment: @MrDrProfessorTyler the code you posted can be adapted by just replacing Boolean/boolean with Integer/int. For readability's sake you'd probably also want to change Flag/flag to Value/value.

Comment: I know but what is the BooleanChangeDispatcher that it implements?  Can that be used with Integers?

Comment: Ok so someone suggested to look up interfaces and now I somewhat figured this out.  I'll figure it out on my own I think thanks peoples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a class capable of registering listeners. Below is a mocked up example. It might even compile as is (assuming you write the corresponding `VocalIntegerListener` interface exists and is implemented somehow... it's pretty simple).

```
class VocalInteger {

    private int value;
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    Set<VocalIntegerListener> listeners; // assume interface exists - it's easy


    public VocalInteger() {
        this(0);
    }

    public VocalInteger(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        listeners = new HashSet<VocalIntegerListener>();
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        synchronized(lock) {
            int oldValue = this.value;
            this.value = value;
            for(VocalIntegerListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.fireChangedEvent(oldvalue, value); // assume exists
            }
        }
    }

    public void registerListener(VocalIntegerListener listener) {
        synchronized(lock) {
            listeners.add(listener);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I guess I am asking how to I create such an interface?

Comment: Some of this can be done with [`Observable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) (if people still use that class).

Comment: @glowcoder: ouch.  My JCIP book is crying.  What if different threads are used to register listener(s) and to call *setValue*?  ; )    I mean, for listeners: *List* and *new CopyOnWriteArrayList*, sure...  But *Set* and unsynchronized *add*?  Ouch.  Just ouch.  : )

Comment: @MrDrProfessorTyler: if you don't know how to create an interface, then I don't think Stack Overflow is the place to be looking for help on that. You need to consult whichever textbook or tutorial website you're using, or ask whoever is teaching you the language to explain how to create interfaces.

Comment: I am teaching myself Java only on the internet because I do not have the money to buy a book and I only have the internet plus I cannot ask anywhere else because I only get hate so please just bear with me on this one.

Comment: @user988052 If multiple threads use it, then it will fire them for each use, as you would expect. In fact, with this way you know when another thread changed the value. For the add, yes that would require synchronization.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky I wasn't aware of this class, but it seems to do the exact same thing. I'd say it's a good fit.

Comment: @MrDrProfessorTyler: if you don't have a book or a teacher, that's fine. The problem is that you don't seem to be making much of an effort to figure out your problems on your own before turning to an (ostensibly expert-level) Q&A site. For instance, given that you have a class which does what you need for booleans, you could easily have just tried replacing `boolean` with `int` and `Boolean` with `Integer` and seeing what happens. If it doesn't work, and you can't figure out the cause of the error (including by searching the web), _that's_ when you come to Stack Overflow.

Comment: "listener.fireChangedEvent(oldvalue, value);" why should a listener fire an event? A listener should be informed about an event. (Probably just a naming issue here.)

Comment: @glowcoder: Uh!? You commented: *"In fact, whith this way you know when another thread changed the value"* and *"yes, that would require synchronization"*.  I'm sorry but these two sentences do not compute.  My point was precisely that if you register a listener from another thread then, because your synchronization is broken, no, you are definitely **not** guaranteed to *"know when another thread changed the value"*.  That is precisely my point.  At 20K+ rep, instead of defending your broken piece of code, why don't you simply fix it by editing your answer?  ; )

Comment: @user I had intended to edit the answer, I had a wife in my ear and never got to it last night. Chill out. The point is that only the add requires synchronization, not the firing of the events. And the synchronization isn't broken, it simply *isn't*. I'm not defending broken code, as I admitted full well that it 1) needed synchronization in the comments, and 2) that this was a mocked up example that needs work in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at "Java Beans" and "bound properties" for the standard approach how to listen for property changed events:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/